# loop error - fixing the loop means breaking something else and vice versa

Tags: java, loops

I've been struggling with this loop assignment. I can make the program work as intended, however, it is at the cost of having extra text at the end if the user enters no values. If I make the code so that the user who enters no values doesn't have this extra text (i.e. the max number is 0 and the count for the max number is 0), the loop doesn't work. My code is included below. What is going on?

```
//Name:
//Date:
//File:
//Description: Program that allows the user to enter numbers and determine the maximum value as well as count how many times that maximum value is entered.

import java.util.Scanner;

public class lab4b_hmcka
{
    public static void main (String [] args)
    {
    //variables
    int num1, num2, max1 = 0, max2 = 0, count = 0, maxCount = 0;

    System.out.println("          Find the maximum number");
    System.out.println();

    System.out.print("Enter an integer <0 ends the input>: ");
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    num1 = input.nextInt();

    if (num1 ==0)
    {
        System.out.println("No numbers are entered except 0");
    }

    while (num1 != 0)
    {
        if (maxCount == 0)
        {
            System.out.print("Enter an integer <0 ends the input>: ");
            num2 = input.nextInt();
            max1 = Math.max(num1, num2);
            maxCount = maxCount + 1;
            count = count + 1;
            System.out.print("Enter an integer <0 ends the input>: ");
            num1 = input.nextInt();
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            max2 = Math.max(num1, max1);

            if (num1 == max1)
            {
                maxCount = maxCount + 1;
                count = count + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                count = count + 1;
            }
            System.out.print("Enter an integer <0 ends the input>: ");
            num1 = input.nextInt();
        }


    }

        if (count == 1)
            {
            System.out.println("The maximum number is " + max1);
            }
        else
            {
            System.out.println("The maximum numberis " + max2);
            }
        System.out.println("The count for the max number is " + maxCount);
    }

}
```

Comment: *If I make the code so that the user (...)* What did you change to achieve that?

Comment: There's no need for that `continue;` instruction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you want to achieve and what you tried to achieve that (whatever it is), but I assume you just want to terminate the program if the user wants to quit right away (= enters 0 first). So simply add a return:

```
if (num1 == 0) {
    System.out.println("No numbers are entered except 0");
    return; // Terminate now.
}
```

Comment: Yes. That's what I want to do. I want to terminate the program with just the text above.

Comment: Manu. That's exactly what I wanted to do. return; worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In you if/else statement at the end of the program you are simply checking for the value of count to equal 1.  Which in this case of the user entering zero initially will never be true since we did not enter the while loop where count is incremented for the first time.  Without changing you code too much you can simply do the following:

```
if(count == 1)
{
    int maxVal = Math.max(max1, max2);
    System.out.println("The max number is " + maxVal
    System.out.println("The count for the max number is " + maxCount
}
```

After which you can simply remove the else and that should give you the output that you want.

Also, there are many other optimizations you can do to achieve the same result with less code, but I will leave that for an individual learning experience.  Good luck!